# DriveApp doesn't like new folders?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a folder in My Drive (not in Shared Drive) when I have other folders I access in my Google Apps Script project. This morning I added a new folder next to the other ones, and DriveApp just decided to call it a day.

[image: DriveApp calls it a day]

```
try{ var outbox = DriveApp.getFolderById("ZORMTHISISAVALIDIDPicaX9r"); }catch(e){ Logger.log(e.toString()); }
```

Now, the ID is fine, I know how to grab it as proven by all the other folders which I can access.
I tried to remove all sharing options the root folder had and I'm still stuck.

```
"Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp. at check_for_files (Code:103:25) at __GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call__.gs:1:8"
```

That error is worth mentionning because its NOT out there yet... Usually, this kind of error is just the ID is not an ID, its an ID with something else at the end, etc.

Any help would be spectacular :)

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: try outbox.getFiles();  and learn how to post your code

Comment: @Cooper Thank you! I tried thereafter but it doesn't work since the outbox failed to instantiate. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFiles' of undefined"

Comment: Please post your code so that it's easier to read

Comment: Can you provide the code (not just screenshots) for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Provide more details about how the new folder is getting created.

Comment: try{
  var outbox = DriveApp.getFolderById("ZORMlfRWaN4qSpIHH4uAsCMFLPicaX9r");


}catch(e){
  Logger.log(e.toString());
}

Comment: This is not reproducible on my end. How are you creating the folder? Are you sure that the account executing the script has access to this folder?

Comment: Guys, I think I need to upgrade my posting skills. I just created a new folder and it worked. Thank you for your guidance guys, you're the best!